# PHP - split a string by delimiter

Tags: php, string, split, explode, delimiter

I have a string like this

```
$string = "
##
First name A
Last Name A
email@emailA.com
##<br />
##
First name B
Last Name B
email@emailB.com
##<br />
##
First name C
Last Name C
email@emailC.com
##<br /> 
.......
";
```

and a keyword,

```
$keyword = "email@emailB.com";
```

What i want is when searching for the keyword it outputs the string betwen "## and ##" in this case

```
First name B
Last Name B
email@emailB.com
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You should use some fancy shmancy regex to solve this issue. Have you tried it?

Comment: Can you modify how the string is generated? Or is this passed to you from a third party?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. People like to see that you've given the problem a good try before coming here. Can you should us any code that you have, and we can help you from there.

Comment: use preg_split to turn your string into an array of items, then preg_grep to look for matches (you'll want to preg_quote your search string)

Comment: Take a look at [regular expressions](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/regex/regex.php/). This should help you solve similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions :

```
echo preg_replace('/#+(.*?'.preg_quote($keyword,'/').'.*?)#+/i','$1',$string);
```

Comment: @Kristen Also, try this [regular expression tutorial](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/regex/regex.php/)